# How can I receive email to a smtp server with django framework?

Tags: django, smtp, imap

The company mail that I have been using so far is an IMAP Mail Server, and in the account settings when I reach through ThunderBird, there is also an Outgoing SMTP server. I am unaware of the web development and am currently trying to receive an e-mail to this IMAP server. The project is a Django project. I have tried django-imap-backend to no avail. I cannot simply receive an e-mail whatever I have tried. I tried with my gmail account as well but it didn't work either. I am not sure what I have been missing, I tried every stack-overflow questions related to the issue but couldn't send the e-mail neither with imap-backend nor with my personal gmail account.

at the end of settings.py from mysite(main web app) looks like this one

```
EMAIL_HOST =  'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT =  587
EMAIL_HOST_USER =  'my google email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =  'password'
```

urls.py from the main app: (form is in contact_page app)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("index.urls")),
    path("about/", include("about_page.urls")),
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")), 
    path("contact/", include("contact_page.urls")),
    path("about/products", include("products_page.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("products/", include("products_page.urls") ),
    path("careers/", include("careers.urls")), 
    path("events/", include("newsnevents_page.urls")),
]
```

views.py from the contact_page:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader 
from django.http import Http404

from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, get_connection
from django.conf import settings


# Create your views here.
    # return HttpResponse("website under construction !!!")
def contact_func(request):
    template = loader.get_template("contact_page/contact_page.html")
    context = {
        "contact":"contact_us",
        }
     
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))






def send_email(request):  
   if request.method == "POST": 
       with get_connection(  
           host=settings.EMAIL_HOST, 
     port=settings.EMAIL_PORT,  
     username=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, 
     password=settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, 
     use_tls=settings.EMAIL_USE_TLS  
       ) as connection:  
           subject = request.POST.get("subject")  
           email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER  
           recipient_list = [request.POST.get("email"), ]  
           message = request.POST.get("message")  
           EmailMessage(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list, connection=connection).send()  

   return render(request, 'contact_page.html')
```

and the urls.py from the contact_page

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.contact_func, name="contact_page"),
    path("", views.send_email),
]
```

Comment: Hello. Maintainer of the django-imap-backend here. I am not sure what exactly your problem is from the issue. What kind of errors you have and what do you need to achieve.